# In a table: Problem equalling the width of only three columns

Tags: tables, columns, multirow, width, multicolumn

I am writing a thesis in a large .tex file in Vim. As I show in this image, the  first, second and third column have different spacing (width):

[image]

This is the code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Números cuánticos \\[-0.1cm] del estado excitado\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\\[-0.95cm]Frecuencias \\[-0.2cm] de absorción \\[-0.2cm] experimentales \\[-0.2cm] (cm\textsuperscript{-1})\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-3}
$v _{1}$ & $v _{2}$ & $v _{3}$ &  \\ \hline
$0$ & $1$ & $0$ & $1594{.}59$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0$ & $0$ & $3656{.}65$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $0$ & $1$ & $3755{.}79$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $2$ & $0$ & $3151{.}40$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $1$ & $1$ & $5332{.}00$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $2$ & $1$ & $6874{.}00$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $0$ & $1$ & $7251{.}60$ \\ \hline
$1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $8807{.}05$ \\ \hline
$2$ & $0$ & $1$ & $10613{.}12$ \\ \hline
$0$ & $0$ & $3$ & $11032{.}36$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I would like to make first, second and third column the same width.

The rest of the tables in the .tex file are fine, except for this particular table. This way, I would not prefer to write commands in the preamble, due to this will modify all tables.

I would only like to equal the space of first, second and third columns only in this particular table.

My preamble is this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\parindent 1 true cm
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{eufrak}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx,epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,super]{natbib} 
\setcitestyle{square} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}    
\pagestyle{fancy}                                     
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\thechapter .\ #1}{}}         
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection .\ #1}{}} 
\lhead{\nouppercase}
\rhead{\nouppercase}
\fancyhead[LE]{{\sf \leftmark}}                                 
\fancyhead[RE]{}                                                
\fancyhead[RO]{{\sf \rightmark}}                              
\fancyhead[LO]{} 
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{}                                                         
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}                                
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{courier}
\begin{document}
```

I would appreciate very much if someone could help me, making tests with my preamble, and the code that introduces the table. (I am writing the thesis .tex file in Vim).

Comment: Similar: [Table with multi column](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159908/5764) (but not adequately solved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a fixed-width set of columns (for the first 3) helps solve this problem:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{C{2em}}c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Números cuánticos \\[-0.1cm] del estado excitado\end{tabular}} 
&  \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}Frecuencias \\[-.3em] de absorción \\[-.3em] experimentales \\[-.3em] (cm\textsuperscript{-1})\end{tabular}} \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
$v _{1}$ & $v _{2}$ & $v _{3}$ &  \\ \midrule
0 & 1 & 0 & 1594.59 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 3656.65 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3755.79 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 3151.40 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 5332.00 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 & 6874.00 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 7251.60 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 8807.05 \\ 
2 & 0 & 1 & \llap{1}0613.12 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & \llap{1}1032.36 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I've done so using a `2em` column of type `C` (centered, with the aid of [`array`](http://ctan.org/pkg/array)).

Comment: The result of `cm\textsuperscript{-1}` looks less than great. You may want to try `cm${}^{-1}` to get a proper minus sign.

Comment: @Werner I appreciate very much the answer. These weeks I have really been trying very hard this solution, but the use of these packages changes the aspect of the rest of the columns of the document, and it turns out to be a complete mess!! Would it be a simplest way to fix (with a command, such as {p}) the first two columns so that the their width results similar to the third column ?

Comment: @DavidC.: Yes. I've used `C{<len>}`, which results in `p{<len>}` with an added `\centering` using the [`array` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/array). If you only use `p{<len>}`, then you will have flush-left content in those columns, or you have to manually add `\centering` (and `\arraybackslash`). You could also use the [`collcell` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/collcell) to set contents centred. However, why would the use of packages "change the aspect of the rest of the columns in your document though"?

Comment: @Werner Thank you for the response. What I meant to say is that there are a lot of "very big tables" in the document, (with    adjustbox commands and so on) and they are modified while following the first answers. I beleive this last answer from today will work, but I don't really know how to implement your answer, could you give me the code for the table and a MWE please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Werner I have been trying the c{<len>} and p{<len>} commands but I am not able to adjust the width of the first two columns. I appreciate very much if you could give me a MWE please. –

Comment: @DavidC.: So you want the widths of columns 1 & 2 to be the same, but different from that of columns 3 & 4? Currently columns 1-3 all have the same width (2em), while column 4 has a natural width as decided by my line breaks.

Comment: @Werner: I finally solved the problem. Could you please take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187744/wrong-index-numeration-even-though-cleardoublepage-before-addcontentsline-has ? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

I switched to `S` columns from the [`sinunitx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sinunitx) package; I also present an option without vertical rules and using the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package (I suppresses packages and commands not relevant to the problem):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openany]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|S[table-format = 3.2]|S[table-format = 3.2]|S[table-format = 3.2]|S[table-format = 5.2]|}
\hline 
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Números cuánticos \\[-0.1cm] del estado excitado\end{tabular}} 
&  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\\[-0.95cm]Frecuencias \\[-0.2cm] de absorción \\[-0.2cm] experimentales \\[-0.2cm] (\si{\per\cm})\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{1-3}
$v _{1}$ & $v _{2}$ & $v _{3}$ &  \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1594.59 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 3656.65 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 3755.79 \\ \hline
0 & 2 & 0 & 3151.40 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 5332.00 \\ \hline
0 & 2 & 1 & 6874.00 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 7251.60 \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 8807.05 \\ \hline
2 & 0 & 1 & 10613.12 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 3 & 11032.36 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format = 3.2]S[table-format = 3.2]S[table-format = 3.2]S[table-format = 5.2]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Números cuánticos \\[-0.1cm] del estado excitado\end{tabular}} 
&  \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}\\[-0.95cm]Frecuencias \\[-0.2cm] de absorción \\[-0.2cm] experimentales \\[-0.2cm] (\si{\per\cm})\end{tabular}} \\ \cmidrule{1-3}
$v _{1}$ & $v _{2}$ & $v _{3}$ &  \\ \midrule
0 & 1 & 0 & 1594.59 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0 & 3656.65 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 3755.79 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 & 3151.40 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & 5332.00 \\ 
0 & 2 & 1 & 6874.00 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & 7251.60 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 8807.05 \\ 
2 & 0 & 1 & 10613.12 \\ 
0 & 0 & 3 & 11032.36 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's better not to use the too restrictive `[h]` float placement specifier.

Comment: You should use `\si{\per\cm}` instead of `\si{\centi\metre^{-1}}`. Also, it should be `S[table-format = 5.2]` in the last column.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg I've introduced your suggestions to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina I appreciate very much the answer. These weeks I have really been trying very hard this solution, but the use of these packages changes the aspect of the rest of the columns of the document, and it turns out to be a complete mess!! Would it be a simplest way to fix (with a command, such as {p}) the first two columns so that the their width results similar to the third column ?